# UITableViewCell cellForRowAtIndexPath calling large number of rows when first scrolling

Tags: sdk, uitableview, ios

I have been working on a problem relating to UITableView and cellForRowAtIndexPath.

I want to give the user the ability to have a very large number of rows much like a large list of email on iPhone. I discovered this problem when I began to create a class that would queue and dequeue groups of records from the database, as needed, in order to conserve memory. I found that when my UITableViewController loads, it then calls cellForRowAtIndexPath for the typical first 10 indexes (0 through 9).  The problem ocurrs when I either click my mouse on the simulator's black outer surface area or I attempt to scroll down on the UITableView using an upward gesture.  At this point, cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called for all remaining indexes.  This happens even if there are 1000+ cells.  I have attempted recreating a VERY SIMPLE project with only 100 indexes (nothing fancy).  It does exactly the same thing.. as soon as I scroll, it calls cellForRowAtIndexPath from positions 10 to 99.

Is this the normal behavior of a UITableView?  Does anyone anyone have any ideas why it is inefficiently calling all rows?

I will say that once this initial pass occurs, it seems like it begins to work correctly.  I am really puzzled by this because it makes it almost impossible to create a class for queuing and de-queuing records as need.

Here is the code on my much simpler sample project:

```
// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return 100;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


 printf("RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = %d\n", indexPath.row);


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

 cell.textLabel.text = @"Example Text";

 return cell;  
}
```

Console:

......
Initial Load of View
......

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 0

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 1

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 2

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 3

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 4

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 5

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 6

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 7

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 8

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 9

......
First Scroll Gesture
......

ootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 11

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 12

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 13

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 14

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 15

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 16

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 17

.
.
I removed a few here to shorten it up
.
.

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 97

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 98

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 99

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 10

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 11

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 12

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 13

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 14

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 15

RootViewController, -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath; // indexPath.row = 16

(gdb)

Thanks for your help.

Eric

**Edit (subsequent day) --> Today I thought to try a real device instead of my simulator.  My iPhone 3GS does not reproduce this strange behavior.  I believe there might be something wrong with the simulator on my machine.  I plan to try another MAC when time permits.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cause of this problem was an application I have installed on my Mac called Cinch.

Cinch is a window management application that adds a windows 'snap' feature to Mac OS.  The program works great otherwise.  Whenever I am working with cellForRowAtIndex path, I'll just have to remember to disable Cinch.

Sadly, I had to reload my entire computer to figure this out!  Hope this is helpful to anyone else experiencing this weird functionality.

Comment: Thanks you so much for this answer. I was stuck on the exact same probme and use Cinch also. You saved me A LOT of wasted time.

Comment: You are my hero! I would have never figured this out.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @geekinit please select your answer

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much! Did anybody inform the developers of Cinch?

Comment: @Klaas, I reported it to Cinch around the time you replied.  They said they were working on it. In the meantime I've gotten in the habit of just disabling and enabling it up in the menu bar. :/

Comment: @geekinit Wow. How did you find this? I was having the problem and couldn't for the life of me explain it. I can report that is also happens with the mac app Moom (which is a window manager type app too). Bizarre!

Comment: @Will I found it when I reloaded my entire computer and subsequently installed Cinch. We've contacted the developer in the past and they claimed to be working on a fix but since people are still experiencing it, I'm not sure. I figure Cinch must be enumerating objects in iOS simulator which leads to this odd functionality.

Answer (score 1):

just in case that some has the same strange problem and has no program like chinch installed: the same behaviour is occuring if you don't use a really individual cellidentifier.. if you just use the standard-identifier out of apple's examples, then it won't work.

everytime you slide your tableview there are entries spinning around. you have to make your cell identifiers unique for every cell. eg.:

```
 NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", indexPath.row];
```

it took me a while to figure this out.. so if somebody finds this thread like me while looking for "uitableview uitableviewcell strange behaviour row switch content on touch slide" he could check this possible error source..

Comment: I think you are missing the whole point of the cell reuse mechanism. When a cell goes off screen, it enters the reuse queue so it can be used again with another index path. This way the same cell object can be used for multiple rows (for performance reasons) via `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier `. So instead of instantiating a lot of cells, you just instantiate as many as needed, that is as many that are visible. If you give every cell a unique reuse identifier you are not reusing your cells at all.

Comment: hmm... then please tell me, how I should populate my cell with data? I do this in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. I create the cell for the coresponding row and add labels with data. when the cell is out of sight other cells are allocated and populated with data. if the user scrolls up again to the first cell it is dequeued from the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method. so every cell is reused, when shown again. how would you do it otherwiese? just one cell object with changing content?

Comment: ok, I tested it again.. it seems, that I'm wrong - it really seems to work now. maybe I had some other problem in my code, which is currently gone..

Comment: This way you are using one cell object with only one row. This way you need as many cells as rows in your table view. The cell reuse mechanism let you reuse one cell object with multiple rows. When a cell goes off screen, it can be used to display another row. If your rows get mixed up when scrolling the table view is because you are not clearing the "old" content when reusing a cell

Comment: Really should delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
    }
```

user this nil for reuseidentifier so it work correctly