# UITableViewController loads all my cells when scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

**The Situation:**

I have a view controller that has a table view, which takes its data from an array. As the data of that array is quite slow to load, i've the elements load themselves on demand (triggered at tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:).

**The Problem:**

At the beginning (i.e. after view did load) it only loads the visible cells (first 6). But then, when you try to scroll it loads everyone else at once! (tested by breakpoint in load, apparently [UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] is called for each row)

**The Code:**

PlayerListDataModel.m

```
@implementation PlayerListDataModel
(...)
-(NSString *)nombre {
    if (!self.loaded) [self load];
    return _nombre;
}
-(void)load {
    NSLog(@"Loading %d", self.sqlId);
    [OMNIGAME loadListCell:self];
    self.loaded = YES;
}
@end
```

PlayerListViewController.m

```
@implementation PlayerListViewController

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { return 1; }

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.jugadores.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString* cellId = @"PlayerListCell";
    PlayerListCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[PlayerListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
    }
    PlayerListDataModel* data =[self.jugadores objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.dem = data.bestDem;
    cell.nombre = data.nombre;
    cell.apellido = data.apellido;
    cell.escudo = data.escudo;
    cell.equipo = data.equipo;
    cell.age = data.edad;
    cell.bandera = data.bandera;
    cell.price = data.price;
    cell.energia = data.energy;
    cell.valor = data.valor;

    return cell;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return tableView.bounds.size.height/7;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return tableView.bounds.size.height/7;
}
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (!self.search) {
        self.search = [[PlayerSearchView alloc] init];
        self.search.search.delegate = self;
    }
    return self.search;
}
```

**The Question:**

Is this intended behavior?
If it is, if there any way to hack around it? If not, What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean it's loading them all, all at once?  Or do you mean it's creating a new cell for each row, and never reusing them?  Note: You create a new PlayerDataModel whether the cell is being reused or not.

Comment: Yes all of them at once, alomst 12.000... (About your note: [Player DataModel load] is only called once per instance, because it sets its loaded flag to true)

Comment: Are you, at any point, expanding the height of your tableView?

Comment: i dont think so. there is a flipfromleft animatin to present the table but its way before the problem: as i said it works perfect until you scroll

Comment: Save the tableview bounds size height to an ivar in the viewDidLoad method and use that in the delegate methods that return the cell and header height. Let us know if this changed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unexpected and indeed unintended behavior. I do not know the implementation of your custom cell but I could not imagine that this could possibly lead to such behavior. In my opinion, nothing is wrong with your implementation of -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: itself.

My suspicion is that either (i) while starting scrolling the bounds of your tableview change in some way, or (ii) some tools installed on your Mac interfere with your simulator. So my suggestions are the following:

(i) As Dhruv Goel suggest try hardcoding the height of the rows. If the bounds of your tableview should shrink, this might lead to some complications (the lower the height of a row, the more rows have to be queued). But I cannot imagine a proper reason why this should happen.

(ii) Do you debug your app via the simulator exclusively? If so, check out this link: [UITableViewCell cellForRowAtIndexPath calling large number of rows when first scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038628/uitableviewcell-cellforrowatindexpath-calling-large-number-of-rows-when-first-sc). It is possible, that tools like those for window management interfere with the simulator.

The last point leads me to another question. Have you checked if this problem occurs in other subclasses of UITableViewController (in this particular project), too?

Comment: You was right Cinch was the problem. This was driving me nuts.

Comment: Yup, Cinch was the problem for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the intended behavior. In fact, this is one of the major functionalities of the UITableView. It just keeps in memory the cells that have to be shown currently in view. So as you scroll, the table view dequeues old cells one by one and reuses them with new data. So in your case initially 5 or 6 cells are in view, and you scroll and new cells are needed, the line :

```
PlayerListCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId];
```

tries to re-use the cells if possible, and if not, new cells are created with :

```
if (!cell) {
cell = [[PlayerListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
}
```

The hack around this would be to not dequeue cells, and create (alloc init) a brand new cell each time, but that's not recommended.

Comment: I couldn't explain my self. I'm saying that I **DON'T** want to load them all at once, but it's happening

Comment: Ah I see .. can you put a NSLog(@"cell number : %d", indexPath.row) .. somewhere inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath method, run it, scroll just a little bit and tell me what's the last log statement in the console ? cell number : X

Comment: wow.. so you mean that just by scrolling a little, the console goes mad and prints out each number from 6 - 11865 ! This is pretty unusual .. are you explicitly calling the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method from somewhere ?

Comment: Can you try hard-coding the tableview cell's height to some value, instead of using tableView.bounds.size.height/7 .. in the heightForRowAtIndexPath method ? And see if you're getting the same result ?

Comment: hardcoding it doesn't change anything and as I've said I had a breakpoint in the load method, and the stack goes right into the [UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] method that should be part of the private API I guess

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, it's documented.

The delegate method:

```
tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:
```

Is called for every cell in your tableview regardless of which ones are on screen.

As the discussion in the documentation says:

> Discussion
>
> The method allows the delegate to specify rows with varying heights. If this method is implemented, the value it returns overrides the value specified for the rowHeight property of UITableView for the given row.
>
> There are performance implications to using tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: instead of the rowHeight property. Every time a table view is displayed, it calls tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: on the delegate for each of its rows, which can result in a significant performance problem with table views having a large number of rows (approximately 1000 or more)